# List values from dynamic aria-label inside HTML span

Tags: python, selenium

I need 5-min prices for some small stocks (yfinance doesn't have them in 5-min increments). Robinhood displays 5-min prices when you mouse hover over the graph.
These values are stored in as follows:
[HTML span element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACe10.png)

I hoped this might return a list of values, but no luck:

```
first_rev = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/main/div/div[1]/section[1]/header/div[1]/h2/span/span")
first_rev.click()
aria_label = first_rev.get_attribute("aria-label")
print(aria_label)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the DOM in your snapshot, `aria-label` is for a single-element which encloses 5 elements inside it with id `sdp-market-price-tooltip`. You have use something like this:

```
prices = driver.find_elements_by_id("sdp-market-price-tooltip")
print(len(prices) # you should get 5 as output here
each_price = [price.text for price in prices]
print(each_price)
```

You may use some extended xpath also, in case the id locator does not work.
`prices = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='sdp-market-price']//span[@id='sdp-market-price-tooltip']`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
value=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h2[@data-testid='PortfolioValue']/span[1]/span[1]").get_attribute("aria-label")
print(value)
```

You can grab the span's attribute value like so.

Furthermore to allow for value to pop up on the screen we use waits.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,60)
value=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h2[@data-testid='PortfolioValue']/span[1]/span[1]")))
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```